# Can the Moga Power Pro be used as a USB controller?

Tags: htc, samsung-nexus-10, game-controllers

So I just received my new Moga Power Pro controller, and I'm extremely disappointed with the latency I'm experiencing with it when playing emulators (both in emulators which can use the Moga "A" mode and ones that use the HID "B" mode) - there's a lag between d-pad presses and responses, the button don't always register presses, etc.  Maybe I'm just spoiled (having only previously used system-specific controllers), but I'm disappointed enough that I may return the controller.  Before I do that, though, I want to try and see if I can reduce the latency at all.  To that end, is it possible to use the pad as a generic USB controller (using the included USB to Micro USB) connector?  Or am I stuck using the Bluetooth connection (which I'm supposing is largely responsible for the latency?)

(I've tried the controller with both my HTC One M8 and my Nexus 10 tablet, both of which are running unrooted 4.4.2; I've tried turning off the Wifi and mobile data, without discernible improvement)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. [The official product website](http://store.mogaanywhere.com/Products/CPFA123252-01) doesn't offer this as a feature, and I've tested with its little brother, the Moga Pro.

Incidentally, I've never noticed any lag or unresponsiveness when using a Moga Pro with a Nexus 10 on 4.2 or 4.4.2. Perhaps your lag can be blamed on a specific app you're running?

Comment: Thanks - it's probably some combination of the emulators and devices I'm using, and perhaps unrealistic expectations.  (When I use the controller on emulators on my PC via the ZeeMouse app, I don't notice any latency at all.)